# Same font has different names in OS and photoshop

Tags: windows, fonts, photoshop

I have a problem with one font:

1) In my OS Windows it installed as 'fontLTStd'

2) I have photoshop psd file. Text in it was written by other user which used the same font, but it name 'font' without LTStd suffix.

I can't edit text in photoshop because font names are different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if photoshop lists the fonts as fontname and in the style, it has Lite and regular. "LTStd" could refer to the style of the font.